# Setting up Visual Studio Code OSX

Tags: macos, bash, visual-studio-code

I'm following the instructions here

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup

Mac OS X

- Download Visual Studio Code for Mac OS X
- Double-click on VSCode-osx.zip to expand the contents
- Drag Visual Studio Code.app to the Applications folder, making it available in the Launchpad
- Add VS Code to your Dock by right-clicking on the icon and choosing Options, Keep in Dock

Tip: If you want to run VS Code from the terminal, append the following to your ~/.bash_profile file (~/.zshrc in case you use zsh).

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* }
```

Now, you can simply type code . in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

When I cut and paste the code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* } into ~/.bash_profile

I get the error

> line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

when I source ~/.bash_profile

I can't work out what the issue is in that line of code

running open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" in the terminal opens code just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What else do you have in `~/.bash_profile` ? Maybe you should post the whole thing ?

Comment: that line is the only thing in there...brand new macbookpro :)

Comment: The error message says line 7 though ?

Comment: If you declare the function on a single line it must end with a semi-colon - just before the closing brace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the command. You can't skip it if you want to write a function in a single line:

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*; }
#                                                                      ^
```

[Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) says:

> A function may be "compacted" into a single line.

```
fun () { echo "This is a function"; echo; }
#                                 ^     ^
```

> In this case, however, a semicolon must follow the final command in
>   the function.

```
fun () { echo "This is a function"; echo } # Error!
#                                 ^

fun2 () { echo "Even a single-command function? Yes!"; }
#                                                    ^
```

Comment: In my case `$*` didn't open the file I wanted. This worked for me: `code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $@; }`

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the following code instead of that line

```
code()
{
    VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
}
```